# TexWorks from MiKTeX vs new version of TexWorks

Tags: miktex, texworks

I have installed the TeXworks 0.6.1, the lastest version. Now I have this new Texworks version and the version from MiKTex.

My question is, what is the best way to procede:

1. Update the Texworks from Miktex? If so, which package to update?
2. Uninstall Texworks from Miktex? If so, how to do it and then relate with the new Texworks version?

Thanks!

**EDIT** 
The MiKTeX Version is : MiKTeX 2.9.5870
The TeXWorks in MikTeX: 0.4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TeXWorks for MiKTeX is a inbuild version and not updated to the very new version 0.6.1.   With that I mean, that MiKTeX uses special directorys for the files needed for TeXWorks, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\texworks.exe
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\texworks\help\Manual\en
```

If you compare that with the original zip file of TeXWorks you will find:

```
C:\Users\Internet\Documents\TeXWorks\share
C:\Users\Internet\Documents\TeXWorks\texworks-help
C:\Users\Internet\Documents\TeXWorks\TeXworks.exe
```

with the english and french manual in directory `texworks-help` and the used fonts and program `poppler` in directory `share`.

So if you want to use the current version (until it is integrated to MiKTeX) use the TeXWorks installer. Check if the installer added the relevant path to variable `path` and move it, if neccessary before the MiKTeX directorys in the path.  Then you can be sure that the new TeXworks is called, if you start it from your terminal with `texworks`.

But see, that the old version is still installed and will be started, if you use the app `TeXWorks` installed by MiKTeX.  And see that the predefined typesets from MiKTeX are gone and you have to recreate it by your own ...

Comment: Thank you :) I changed the path of the executable .tex to the new version and I installed the languages packages in the new version!